# All armies and fleets destroyed - Still in Game?

Tags: diplomacy

Quick Diplomacy question.

If a country has had all armies and fleets destroyed but still have a home supply centre that hasn't been taken are they still in the game ?

I believe yes but not sure. Cheers

Comment: Even if it wasn't a home supply center they are technically not eliminated from the game.  They could be included in a draw despite having no pieces on the board (and no way of getting more).  You aren't eliminated until you have zero centers during a winter phase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote below is part of a rule.
So yes, I would play it like you suggest, because your situation matches this rule in the strictest sense (one center versus zero units).

> If he/she has more centers than units, he/she may build units by placing them, one in each unoccupied supply center, in his/her home country only (provided that such supply centers are still under his control).