# Diplomacy: No units but 1 Non-Home Supply Center

Tags: house-rules, diplomacy

Hello Diplomacy enthusiasts.

I was recently playing an online game of Diplomacy with my friends and unfortunately drew Italy. All was going well until I was overrun by Turkey who made quick work out of Austria (and eventually went on to solo) and he agreed to let me survive in Tunis with an army so long I fight France and let him take my lands, as you do.

Anyways, in Spring 1911, he supported his fleet into my poor, 1 SC nation and I disbanded my unit. After a bit of negotiating, he vacated Tunis in the fall and I had 1 Supply Center that I couldn't build in, and 0 troops. When the game ended.

My question is whether I would have gained a share of the pot if I tied with the others.

Also, does it count as surviving?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the indicated question.  That question is about a home supply center whereas this one is about a non-home supply center (the difference being that in the other question, you can actually build a unit and potentially go on to do something whereas here you cannot do anything but may technically still be in the game).

Comment: Perhaps, but the comment on the other question does answer this one, stating that the player is still in the game despite having no units. Interestingly, the rules on Hasbro's website (dated 1999) don't actually mention elimination of players, and additionally fold the Winter phase into Fall and allow only for a single player to win.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok So I found the answer on this post:
[All armies and fleets destroyed - Still in Game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15462/all-armies-and-fleets-destroyed-still-in-game)

@bwarner said:

Even if it wasn't a home supply center they are technically not eliminated from the game. They could be included in a draw despite having no pieces on the board (and no way of getting more). You aren't eliminated until you have zero centers during a winter phase. – bwarner May 5 '14 at 13:31

So technically I would still be in the game.

Comment: Yup, the supplycenters count.